# Django forms submit radio button value shows up as None

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a django form like this:

```
class HelpForm (forms.form):
    queue = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label=_('What can we help you with today?'),
        required=True,
        choices=()
    )
```

The choices for this form are populated in the views like this:

```
form = HelpForm(initial=initial_data)
    form.fields['queue'].choices = [(q.id, q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)] + \
                                   [('', 'Other')]
```

The default rendering of this form in the templates when called as `{{form.queue}}` is a drop down list. But I needed it as a radio button field, so I did this in my template for each drop down value:

```
<input type="radio" name="help_form" id="order_issues" value="{{form.queue.field.choices.2.0}}"/>
<label for="id_order_issues">{{form.queue.field.choices.2.1}}</label>
```

Now, when I submit this form, the `queue` value shows up as `None` even though I have made a selection and because this is a mandatory field, the form submit fails. Of course the form has other fields and they work as expected. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start by synchronizing the `ChoiceField` instance with the template, for example rename the field to `order_issues`

```
class HelpForm (forms.form):
    order_issues = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        label=_('What can we help you with today?'),
        required=True,
        choices=()
    )
```

Of course the view must also change:

```
form = HelpForm(initial=initial_data)
form.fields['order_issues'].choices = [(q.id, q.title) for q in Queue.objects.filter(allow_public_submission=True)] + \
                                      [('', 'Other')]
```

And finally the template:

```
<input type="radio" name="order_issues" id="id_order_issues" value="{{form.order_issues.field.choices.2.0}}"/>
<label for="id_order_issues">{{form.order_issues.field.choices.2.1}}</label>
```

Your code is not working because django needs that the `input`'s `name` attribute to be equal to the name defined in the form class, and the `input`'s `id` attribute must be prefixed by `id`_field_name

HTML stuff: This is extra but it could be useful to understand the impact that the label's for attrib has over the input tag.

Comment: Oh, was not aware of that, would it also work if I changed input name to `queue` instead of changing my code to `order_issues` in two places?

Comment: Changing the name to `queue` worked as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)